# Need Particular Word from the text file in a output file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am having a file.txt file, which contains,

```
1501ac6       Good
1501ac7       Moderate
1501ac8       Poor
```

Now I need only the "Moderate" word from second row as a output in a text file.

Am running the program,

```
@echo off
cls
set /p a=<file.txt | Moderate
echo %a% >output.txt
pause
exit
```

But it fails and ends up with an error...

Comment: Hi Hari Krishna, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you clarify what you are expecting to be returned from the batch file into the text file, and can you paste the error you are getting into your question, also.

Comment: i am expecting and needed output is from second row  second word (Moderate) in a single text file. Nothing as error. What i need, is not coming as output. Please help my dear bro #Paul

Comment: `for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in (file.txt) do echo %%a>output.txt & goto continue` followed by `:continue` label

Answer (score 1):

`set /p` is not the right tool here.

```
find /I "Moderate" file.txt > output.txt
```

If you need only the first string of that line(s):

```
for /f %%a in ('find /I "Moderate" file.txt') do >>output.txt echo %%a
```

Comment: It not works ! Shows different output. But i need only the word Moderate as an output. I tried with the token=2 command. But it shows "Poor" word as an output. How to make it to show the second line , second word "Moderate" as the only word of that output file . Please Help #Stephan

Comment: @HariKrishna: If you only need 'Moderate' as the output, then how are you going to tell which file this is associated to? After all, your filename is simply `output.txt`.

Comment: @HariKrishna: Ignore the file and just `echo Moderate`? Somehow I seem to fail to understand what you want :(